# Parsing Mandrill JSON Response with jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a php script which is sucessfully connecting to and sending an email through the Mandrill API. As dumb as it sounds, I can't figure out how to parse the following JSON reponse:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => matt@mattblum.com
            [status] => sent
            [_id] => eedced1b58e24668907024e937afeabd
            [reject_reason] => 
        )

)
```

Full ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'mandril.php',
    data: formData.serialize(),
    success: function(returnedData) {
        var response = returnedData;
        status = response[0]['status']; // I've also tried different combos of this

        if(status == "sent") {
            msgs('Message sent!');
            var alreadySent = true;
        } else {
            msgs(response);
        }

      },
      error: function(e) {
          console.log(e);
      }
```

The code I've tied to read the 'status' element:

```
console.log(response[0]['status']);
console.log(response[0][1]);
console.log(response[0][0]['status']);
console.log(response[0][0][1]);
```

Another thing I don't understand is that:

```
var response = returnedData;
console.log(response[0]);
```

Returns a capital 'A' and nothing else.

I'm sure it's something dumb that I'm doing but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `success : function(responseData) {console.log(responseData)}` return?

Comment: The whole array as formatted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt,
Looks like your PHP array syntax is being captured as text and sent as a response to your post. If you specify JSON on the Mandrill/PHP side (and the ajax/jquery side) your jquery call should be able to parse the response.

console.log(response[0]) is returning 'A' because that's the first character of the string.

Add 'json' on the query side and json_encode($response) on the php side.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much Ben!